# Is junit a framework library or unit testing term or both?

Tags: java, junit

I have gone thru [junit wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit) and other links on net

What i understand is that junit is framework library provided by `org.junit` with which we can write test cases. some alternatives for writing
test cases are powermock,jmockit,easymock etc

But i have seen people asking which junit frame work  you are using ?  They mean powermock/jmockit/easymock. Here is my confusion
I believe junit framework and other mentioned frameworks are separate frameworks which can be used separately or combined together . so
believe right question should which unit testing framework  you are using not junit framework ?

Am i correct here when i say other works like powermock,jmockit,easymock etc  can be used separately without junit framework (as they are also full fledged
junit framework to do unit testing ) or they have to be used in combination of junit frmework as other mentioned frameworks are just mocking fremworks?

Comment: Powermock & friends are mocking frameworks, as is obvious from their names. Draw your own conclusions from that (and read some documentation too).

Comment: They are *not* "full fledged unit testing frameworks".

Comment: @DaveNewton it means I have to use some xunit (like junit, TestNG) with powermock or jmockito or other mocking frameworks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i have seen people asking which junit frame work you are using ?

If I ask you what java frameworks you are using it is likely you would not mention the Java API, but rather Spring or Dropwizard or... That you are using Java is given.

JUnit is the unit testing framework (an alternative to it would be testng).

> [Do] I have to use some xunit (like junit, TestNG) with powermock or jmockito or other mocking frameworks ?

You don't have to, you could roll your own or use a mocking library in an app. Both would be terrible ideas but (most) mocking libraries are not tied to a testing framework.

> some alternatives for writing test cases are powermock,jmockit,easymock etc

No they are not. They are libraries you can use to make testing easier (or  harder if you abuse them).

> Do I have to use powermock or jmockito or other mocking frameworks with xunit (like junit, TestNG)

Not at all. A lot of the time I find manually rolled stubs a better option than library created mock.

Comment: thanks mlk. Actually my question is other way around that `[Do] I have to use powermock or jmockito or other mocking frameworks with xunit (like junit, TestNG) as  powermock/jmockito are just mocking framework and can not be used independently for unit testing?`

Comment: looks like I was not clear in my question. My question is powermock or jmockito  or manually rolled stubs are just helper for creating mocks but we want to use them for unit testing they have to be used with some xunit framework like junit or testing. is that correct now ?

Comment: Significantly less clear. Are you asking if you have to use some from of [test double](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) in order to write unit tests?

Comment: Ok let me try again. Can I write unit test case with just using powermock or jmockito  but not including junit(org.junit ) or testNG or any other xunit implementation ?  I believe answer should be no

Comment: Why do you believe the answer should be no?

Comment: As powermock or jmockito are just mocking framework but to write the unit test case like assert statement,test fixtures, test runner we will be needing xunit framework like junit/testNG ?

Comment: Thanks a lot ml for patience